# How I can keep track of xml next children to print this html table with correct format using php

Tags: php, xml

I want to fetch some data from database as xml and print them inside a html table using php.

here is my php code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($ru) or die("Error: Cannot create object");  
    echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">';        
    foreach ($xml->employee->children() as $key=>$value){
                if($key == 'PAYMSTR_SALHDNM' ){                  
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">'.$value.'</th>';                    
                    echo '<td  style="border: 1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">'.$value.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">'.$key.'</th>';
                    echo '<td  style="border: 1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">'.$value.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }   
    echo '</table>';
```

Now I am getting this output:
[image]

But want to make each value of tag  PAYMSTR_SALHDNM  as table head  [its done ]and each value of tag  PAYMSTR_AMOUNT  as table data for tag  PAYMSTR_SALHDNM

Like the following image:
[image]

i think if, somehow i can keep track of `next $xml->employee->children()` and its value,then i can bring such correct format.Please help me on that.Thanks

Updates: Here is my Table:
[image]

Here is my xml:

```
<employee><id>FMCSC00015</id><year>2016</year><month>1</month><paymstr_salhdnm>BASIC PAY</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>35600</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>ASSOCIATION SUBSCRIPTION</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>240</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>TELEPHONE ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>800</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>HOUSE RENT DEDUCTION</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>2587.5</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>MEDICAL ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>700</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>GAS BILL</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>450</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>DEARNESS ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>6000</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>LIFE INSURANCE PREMIUM (D)</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>1718</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>PF SUBSCRIPTION</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>3560</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>PF ADVANCE LOAN</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>2796</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>BENEVOLENT FUND</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>1780</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>HEALTH INSURANCE PREMIUM</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>150</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>STUDENT WELFARE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>3</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>MUNICIPAL TAX &amp; SWEAPER CH.</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>18</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>STAIR CASE LIGHT CHARGES</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>1.25</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>CLUB</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>207</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>TEACHER'S FAMILY WELFARE ASSOC</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>10</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>MOTOR GARAGE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>500.5</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>RESEARCH ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>1500</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>SONALI BANK LOAN-3</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>5728</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>SONALI BANK LOAN-4</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>23490</paymstr_amount></employee>
```

Comment: Please show us an example of the XML input your are talking about.

Comment: Thanks  @hherger. I've added the actual table data  on my post.on that table, you can see columns PAYMSTR_SALHDNM, PAYMSTR_AMOUNT.these are the columns that  i am returning as xml tag and putting on html  table.

Comment: I meant the XML. Please to a _var_dump($ru)_ and post it here.

Comment: Thanks @hherger. I've added the xml  on my post.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. The basic idea is to…

- in a first loop extract all the header data
  (the first three header items to be pre-initialised),
- in a second loop select data and build table, where the loop index is the index into the header table.

### Code

```
    <?php
    $ru = "..."; // Has pre-defined content
    $xml=simplexml_load_string($ru) or die("Error: Cannot create object");  

    // Collect and create headers
    $headers = array('ID', 'YEAR', 'MONTH'); // Pre-define headers
    foreach ($xml->paymstr_salhdnm as $key=>$header) {
        $headers[] = (string)$header;
    }

    // Create data table
    $hindex=0;
    echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">'; 
    foreach ($xml->children() as $key=>$value){
        if (strtolower($key) == 'paymstr_salhdnm' ) continue; // header data, so ignore
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '   <td style="border: 1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">'.((isset($headers[$hindex])) ? $headers[$hindex] : '&nbsp;').'</td>';
        echo '   <td style="border: 1px solid black;  border-collapse: collapse;">'.$value.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $hindex++;
    }
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also output the key/value pairs as a definition list, using php like:

```
<?php

$ru = <<<XMLDATA
<employee><id>FMCSC00015</id><year>2016</year><month>1</month><paymstr_salhdnm>BASIC PAY</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>35600</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>ASSOCIATION SUBSCRIPTION</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>240</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>TELEPHONE ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>800</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>HOUSE RENT DEDUCTION</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>2587.5</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>MEDICAL ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>700</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>GAS BILL</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>450</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>DEARNESS ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>6000</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>LIFE INSURANCE PREMIUM (D)</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>1718</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>PF SUBSCRIPTION</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>3560</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>PF ADVANCE LOAN</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>2796</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>BENEVOLENT FUND</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>1780</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>HEALTH INSURANCE PREMIUM</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>150</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>STUDENT WELFARE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>3</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>MUNICIPAL TAX &amp; SWEAPER CH.</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>18</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>STAIR CASE LIGHT CHARGES</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>1.25</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>CLUB</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>207</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>TEACHER'S FAMILY WELFARE ASSOC</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>10</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>MOTOR GARAGE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>500.5</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>RESEARCH ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>1500</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>SONALI BANK LOAN-3</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>5728</paymstr_amount><paymstr_salhdnm>SONALI BANK LOAN-4</paymstr_salhdnm><paymstr_amount>23490</paymstr_amount></employee>    
XMLDATA;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($ru) or die("Error: Cannot create object");  


// Collect and create headers
$headers = array('ID', 'YEAR', 'MONTH');  

foreach ($xml->paymstr_salhdnm as $key=>$header) {
    $headers[] = (string)$header;
}

echo '<dl>';

$hindex=0;

foreach ($xml->children() as $key=>$value){
    if (strtolower($key) == 'paymstr_salhdnm' ) continue;

    echo  (isset($headers[$hindex])) ? PHP_EOL . "<dt>{$headers[$hindex]}</dt>" : PHP_EOL . '<dt></dt>';

    echo "<dd>$value</dd>";

    $hindex++;
}

echo '</dl>';
```

And the outcome being a list of "definition-terms" with the matching "definition-value", like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/9c2xaa27/